# c#: Counting elements in a list from a specified index

Tags: c#, count

I am a beginner in c# and don't really understant all of "the things" that VS throws at me in terms of overloads (int IEnumerable int.Count int and so on) yet. I am trying to use .Count(). How do I get a number of remaining elements in a list – how do I start counting from a certain index in a list?

Comment: Which _"the things"_ are you talking about? No one can help you without code and details

Comment: When querying, *Linq* can be convenient: e.g `int myCount = myEnumerable.Skip(5).Count(item => item > 7);` here we count all items which are bigger than `7` starting from `5`th item (we skip `0..4` indexes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, let's say you have a List with 10 strings: "A" to "J". You are at "C", which is index 2 in the list. Therefore you get the count of elements in the list (`list.Count` property - not the method `IEnumerable.Count()`) and subtract (index + 1) from the count. So in this case you would have `10 - (2 + 1) = 7` elements left.

There is a difference between `List<T>.Count` and `Enumerable.Count()` - they both count the elements and they both return the same number, but they are implemented differently. There are a lot of great answers about how `List<T>` is different from `IEnumerable<T>` so I won't go into it here, but you're welcome to research it more.